# Constructing MObject from existing object name in Maya scene

Tags: c++, api, maya, construct

How can I construct an MObject with Maya API having access to only the existing object **name** in the scene?

Answer (score 2):

It was easy actually!

`MSelectionList selection;
    selection.add(MString(objName));
    selection.getDependNode(0, object);`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more idiomatic to use `MGlobal.getSelectionListByName()` which does the same thing.